# convert DD/MM/YYYY to YYYYMMDD to compare it with a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, string-comparison

I wanted to convert Date to a string by removing "/" and to make it YYYYMMDD to compare it with first 6 characters of a given string.

HTML:

```
    <div class="cust-dob">
      <span class="input-append date form-control2" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" placeholder="">
         <input class="span2 valid" size="9" name="custdob" id="custdob" type="text" placeholder="DOB" value="" readonly="" aria-invalid="false">
           <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </span>
   </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control2 resizeselect" name="nric" id="nric" placeholder="" size="12" value="">
```

Script:

```
$("#nric").blur(function(){
  var ic = $("#nric").val();
  var dob = $("#cust-dob").val();
  var updateddob = new Date(dob.split("/").join(""));
  if(ic != updateddob){
    alert("wrong nric");
  }
  console.log(updateddob);
});
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Did you forget the # in `$("cust-dob").val();`? So it should be `$("#cust-dob").val();`...

Comment: @Andy `$(".cust-dob").val();`

Comment: why not use a datepicker and compare both dates not strings?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I don't think so. It's definitely an ID.

Comment: @Andy then `$('#custdob').val()`

Comment: Shalem Madhukar   actually your requirement is pretty unclear. can you add some sample input date in your question and then what desired output you want based on that input date, tell that one also

Comment: dob format: DD/MM/YYYY.      
NRIC format: YYYYMMDD123457.
So, we need to split first 6 numbers and need to compare with dob

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to compare two differently formatted date strings. I have two ways you can do this:

1. Keep it to string operations
2. Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

You seem to be trying to use date conversion and string operations at the same time, which can only add confusion. Keep it simple.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var a = '20111031';
var b = '31/10/2011';

// STRING OPERATIONS:

console.log( b.split('/')[0] === a.split('').slice(6).join('') && b.split('/')[1] === a.split('').slice(4, 6).join('') && b.split('/')[2] === a.split('').slice(0, 4).join(''));

// true

// MOMENT.JS:

console.log(moment(b, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format() === moment(a, 'YYYYMMDD').format())

// true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```